# Modal form will only submit and work twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

My modal with a form submitted via AJAX works fine if I open it the first time and submit it. After that, if I close the modal or if I submit the data a second time, the modal won't work correctly so a click on the submit button won't happen.

What am I doing wrong?

Modal (on load the form by ajax)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="settings" role="basic" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="../../../assets/global/img/loading-spinner-grey.gif" alt="" class="loading">
                <span> &nbsp;&nbsp;Daten werden geladen - bitte warten... </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Final Modal with form

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <h4>Kundennummer</h4>
        <div>
            <form id="userForm_settings" method="post">                                    
                <div class="form-group form-inline ">
                    <label>Startwert</label>
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" id="form_KD_NO_START" name="KD_NO_START" value="55" placeholder="Bsp. 10001" type="text">
                </div>    
                <p><a class="btn green-meadow save_button" href="#" id="settings"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> speichern</a></p>
                <input name="DS" value="3" type="hidden">
                <input name="step" value="update" type="hidden">
            </form>                                    
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn dark btn-outline">schließen</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../../../module/1/code/js_modals.php?lang=de" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Here is the JS code:

```
enter $(function(){ 
    //MiniColors
    $('.demo').each(function() { $(this).minicolors({ theme: 'bootstrap' }); });                                    

    //Formularhaendling
    //$.post( "kontaktgruppen.php", $( "#userForm" ).serialize() );

    //$('#save').click(function () { 
    $('.save_button').click(function () { 
        alert("you've click");
        var  formID = $(this).attr('id');
        var formDetails = $('#userForm_'+formID);
        //alert("ID"+formID);

        if (formID=='settings') {
            var fileurl='settings.php'; 
        } else { 
            var fileurl='kontaktgruppen.php';
        }

        // $('#modalOne').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {
        // tinyMCE.editors=[];
        // });

        // $('.modal-body').html(data).promise().done(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: fileurl,
            type: "post",
            //cache: false,
            //dataType: "html",           
            //data: $( "#userForm" ).serialize(),
            //data: $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize(),
            //data: $(this).parent().serialize()
            //data: $(this).serialize(),
            data: formDetails.serialize(),
            //data: $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize(),
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                displayAjaxMessage("Sorry, there was an error");
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var res = $.parseJSON(result);

                if (formID=='settings') { 
                    $("#settings .modal-body").html(res.content); 
                } else { 
                    $("#kontaktgruppen .modal-body").html(res.content); 
                }

            if (res.code==10) {
                toastr.options = {  "closeButton": true,  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",    "showDuration": "1500" }
                toastr.success("", "<?php echo $lang['mod1'][33]; ?>");
            }

            if (res.code==30) {
                toastr.options = {  "closeButton": true,  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",    "showDuration": "1500" }
                toastr.success("", "<?php echo $lang['mod1'][39]; ?>"); 
            }

            if (res.code==99) {
                toastr.options = {  "closeButton": true,  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",    "showDuration": "1500" }
                toastr.error("<?php echo $lang['mod1'][35]; ?>", "<?php echo $lang['mod1'][34]; ?>");
            }


            //location.reload(); //Reload der ganzen Seite
            //$("#kontaktgruppen").load("kontaktgruppen.php");
            //$("#kontaktgruppen .modal-title").text('Aktualisiert');    
       }
   });       
});  


$(".delete_group").click(function(){    
    var del_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'kontaktgruppen.php',
        data:'delete_id='+del_id,
        success:function(result) {
            var res = $.parseJSON(result);
            $("#kontaktgruppen .modal-body").html(res.content);
            if (res.code==20) {   
                toastr.options = {  "closeButton": true,  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",    "showDuration": "1500" }
                toastr.warning("", "<?php echo $lang['mod1'][36]; ?>");
            } else { 
                toastr.options = {  "closeButton": true,  "positionClass": "toast-top-right",    "showDuration": "1500" }
                toastr.error("", "<?php echo $lang['mod1'][37]; ?>");
            }
        }
    });
}); 

//Reset the modals
//$('#settings').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    //$(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    //$(this).empty();
    //$(this).removeAttr('style');
//});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

rather than handling event on element

```
 $('.save_button').click(function () { ....
```

you should handle it at document level

```
$(document).on('.save_button','click',function(){  ...
```

this way if you reload the form without reloading the whole window i.e. partial reload the event will propagate from document to the target

or to be more specific rather than document you can use wrapper tag of form which will not re-render if form reloaded.

Comment: Does same go for submit? I mean, can you do `$(document).on('.save_button','submit',function(){  ...`?

Comment: Hi, if i chang "$('.save_button').click(function () {" with your code "$(document).on('.save_button','click',function(){ " submit works anymore!?

Comment: try it, it should work, you can also use 'submit' instead of 'click'